# useEffect don't fire when the state is modified by a child component through props callback

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a Flatlist component that passes its state and its setState to a child component. The child component does change the state of the parent (tried showing state using setinterval and console.log) but I can't listen when the change occurs. I tried using

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(`listState:`, state);
},[state]);
```

But it never fires except on mounting. Here is my code.

```
// in CheckboxFlatList.js  (parent)
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Text } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import CheckBox from "./Checkbox";


function CheckboxFlatList(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`listState:`, state);
    },[state]);

    // setInterval(() => {
    //     console.log(`listState:`, state);
    // },3000 );

    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View>
                        <View>
                            <CheckBox id={item.id.toString()} listState={state} stateMerge={setState} isChecked={state.some(x => x === item.id.toString())} />
                            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )}
            />
        </View >
    );
}
```

```
// in Checkbox.js  (child)
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, memo } from 'react';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

export default memo(

    function Checkbox(props) {
        let { listState, stateMerge, isChecked, id } = props;
        const [toggleCheckBox, setToggleCheckBox] = useState(isChecked);

        const mounted = useRef();
        useEffect(() => {
            if (!mounted.current) {  // do componentDidMount logic
                mounted.current = true;
            } else {  // do componentDidUpdate logic

                if (toggleCheckBox) {
                    if (!listState.some(x => x === id)) {   //to avoid a duplication bug
                        listState.push(id);
                    }

                } else {
                    while (listState.some(x => x === id)) {   //to avoid a duplication bug
                        let index = listState.indexOf(id);
                        if (index !== -1) listState.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                }
                stateMerge(listState);
            }
        });


        return (
            <CheckBox checked={toggleCheckBox} size={40} onPress={() => {
                setToggleCheckBox(!toggleCheckBox);

            }} />
        );
    });
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: So you are passing a state and an hook to a memoized component. Then modify state (without using his hook) into another hook appling a componentDidMount logic using an useRef and there is something that it doesn't work... :)

Comment: @Giovanni_Esposito I only started react native a few days ago, that's why. Can you explain to me the errors you mentioned in more detail? It would really help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is a band-aid solution and introduces another bug: the effect will be fired if a no-op update is performed on the state.

The `useEffect` callback is not fired because the referential identity of the dep is unchanged. Forcing a new referential identity by redefining an object only treats the symptom. Generally you should aim to address the root cause instead.

In your case the referential identity not changing is a symptom of a violation of an assumption of React state. Changes to state should always be done using the appropriate setter function/method, never by mutating.

The offending code in the following block mutates React state.

```
            if (toggleCheckBox) {
                if (!listState.some(x => x === id)) {   //to avoid a duplication bug
                    listState.push(id);
                }

            } else {
                while (listState.some(x => x === id)) {   //to avoid a duplication bug
                    let index = listState.indexOf(id);
                    if (index !== -1) listState.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
            stateMerge(listState);
```

We can fix it by eliminating mutation. When we write it without using mutation the identity naturally changes only when the value changes.

```
        stateMerge(listState => 
            if (toggleCheckBox) {
                if (!listState.some(x => x === id)) {   //to avoid a duplication bug
                    return [...listState, id];
                } else {
                    return listState;
                }
            } else {
                return listState.filter(x => x !== id);
            }
        );
```

You should see `useEffect` firing any time the state changes and not firing when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

in your Checkbox.js  Where you calling stateMerge/setState callback

pass listState to stateMerge like this

```
stateMerge([...listState])
```

will fires `useEffect` correctly

Comment: Thank you ! I found the issue a bit after your answer. Here is the explication if someone need : https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15858